# How to re-run redirect rules in Chrome extension with manifest v3?

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am writing a Chrome extension with manifest v3 that will be taking advantage of the `declarativeNetRequest` permission. I have defined the following rule as an example:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": "https://www.google.com/search?q=\\1\\2"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^https?://www\\.google\\.com/search\\?q=(.*?)\\s?(?:dang|frickin)(.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

The intent is to provide a regex for curse words and redirect the search to a new page that has removed the curse words from the search query. This currently works for the first matched word, but the rest of the instances are not removed.

For example, the search query `how to remove a dang frickin xyz` becomes `how to remove a  frickin xyz` right now, but ideally would become `how to remove a xyz`. Is there a way to make the defined rules run more than once, to remove all observed instances of the defined regexes?

I'm not sure if there is a way to accomplish this with regex, or if I can possibly duplicate the rule and re-run it several times via the [`updateStaticRules`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#method-updateStaticRules) function.

My `manifest.json` looks like so:

```json
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
  },
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules_1.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.google.com/"]
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do it with one rule because regexFilter has ultra severe limits, so you'll have to generate a rule per each word. Due to these limits you may have to use a simple urlFilter: 'word' along with requestDomains: ['www.google.com'].

Comment: @wOxxOm that still imposes the same limitation, a word occurring twice in the string wouldn't be removed if the rules only run once.

Comment: Well, there's no solution in a normal ManifestV3 extension. Only a force-installed extension can use the webRequestBlocking permission to handle the request in a blocking chrome.webRequest.